# Aggregate function (Max) on a value in a different table than main fields

Tags: sql, max, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables:

`merchant`: has all the `zipcodes` available for a merchant (If a merchant has 10 locations, it appears in this table 10 times)
Fields: merchant_id, Zipcode. merchant_id is the primary key.

`subdiv`: has all the `zipcodes` in the country and # of subscribers  in each `zip code` Fields:.subs, Zipcode  zipcode is the primary key. Subs is the number of subscribers in the zipcode zone.

I'm looking to get a list of all merchants with a zipcode that has the highest number of subs.

Here is my solution:

```
select mr.merchant_id, m.zipcode 
from merchant mr 
join subdiv su on su.zipcode = mr.zipcode
join (select merchant_id, max(subs) as max_subs 
from merchant mr2 join subdiv su2 on su2.zipcode = mr2.zipcode group by 1
) as mr3 on mr3.merchant_id = mr.merchant_id and su.subs = mr3.max_subs
```

Comment: can you please provide table structure

Comment: @Akshay What do you need to see beside the two columns he's joining on?

Comment: Make sure you have an index on `zipcode` and a composite index on `merchant_id, `subs`.

Comment: By the time that the database engine is performing grouping and aggregation, it really doesn't matter which table(s) the data came from - it's just working with a result set full of data, and with all of the columns produced by the joins, and just needs to know which columns to group on and how to reduce the other columns down to a single value per group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying for ONLY one merchant at a time, you could do this:

```
select mr.merchant_id, mr.zipcode, su.subs
from merchant mr
    join subdiv su on su.zipcode = mr.zipcode
order by su.subs desc
where mr.merchant_id = ?
limit 1
```

Another query that should work (I have not tested it) for multiple merchant_id's at one time is this:

```
select mr.merchant_id, mr.zipcode, su.subs
from merchant mr
    join subdiv su on su.zipcode = mr.zipcode
where su.subs =
    (select max(su2.subs) from subdiv su2 where su2.zipcode in 
        (select mr2.zipcode from merchant mr2 where mr2.merchant_id = mr.merchant_id)
    )
order by mr.merchant_id, mr.zipcode
```

Note that it will return more than one row for a merchant if more than one zip_code have the same number of subscribers that are the max() for that merchant.  This should perform better than the query you have provided if I have not made any syntax errors.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(subs) as Subs,mr.merchant_id, mr.zipcode 
  from merchant mr 
  left join subdiv su on su.zipcode = mr.zipcode
  group by mr.zipcode,mr.merchant_id
```